# Can I store and access any temporary storage on cloud/ container?

Tags: linux, azure, containers, local-storage, cloud

I am relatively new to cloud, so please guide me through complete process.
I have an application that will be hosted on containers in cloud environment. I want some temporary storage on the container or the cloud environment, and access it via my web application (written in C#), meaning I will generate a file and keep it there. First of all, is it possible without costing me extra? Secondly, if it is possible, how can I access the area with C# code? And even if it costs me extra, will I have any access issues?? Also, please let me know the limitations of that free space, in terms of storage, accessibility and cost.

Comment: Temporally means? 1 min? 1 day? 1 year?

Comment: well, something like Temp folder in our systems. Could be anything.

Comment: Which kind of container? docker? ACI? Kubernetes? a mix of them? are you planning to use an App service?

Comment: Kubernetes. Yes, I am planning to use App service

Answer (score 0):

Using an App Service you can store temporal files inside %TMP% folder which is maped to %SYSTEMDRIVE%\local\Temp with no extra cost.

Depending on your App Service Plan you will have from 10GB to 140GB free space to store files. Beware, your files will dissapear if App service is restarted.

Refer to this link:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system